# How to buffer string stream with Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a endless binary stream, now I wish to buffer them each 10000 characters.

```
theFunctionKeepsStreamingString()
.bufferWithCount(10000) //this is not working
.map((data）=>{
    //dealing with each 10000 characters
});
```

But it seems it is not working like this. How do I do this ?

Comment: *"it is not working like this"* is a very general description. It's not working how? What RxJS version you're using?

Comment: Was using rxjs 4 dyntax. This seems changed but not updated in there docs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem here.

Made a test on [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RfQR12XttA9ry4ZMNBiJ?p=preview) :

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

Observable
  .from(characters)
  .bufferCount(3)
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

And it works as expected :
[image]

Comment: You're right, but my problem is in the theFunctionKeepsStreamingString() I had, this function actually a post request with an endless binary data stream response. Angular's HTTP doesn't seem support such endless data stream in Observable, cause it only emit after response transferred completely.

Comment: You should use websockets for that

Comment: But I can't control the server side. I solved my problem in other question